# Compiling C program with VS2012

Tags: c, compilation, visual-studio-2012

My program looks like that

```
/* print_it.c—This program prints a listing with line numbers! */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void do_heading(char *filename);

int line = 0, page = 0;

int main( int argv, char *argc[] )
 {
 char buffer[256];
 FILE *fp;

 if( argv < 2 )
 {
 fprintf(stderr, “\nProper Usage is: “ );
 fprintf(stderr, “\n\nprint_it filename.ext\n” );
 return(1);
 }

 if (( fp = fopen( argc[1], “r” )) == NULL )
 {
 fprintf( stderr, “Error opening file, %s!”, argc[1]);
 return(1);
 }

 page = 0;
 line = 1;
 do_heading( argc[1]);

 while( fgets( buffer, 256, fp ) != NULL )
 {
 if( line % 55 == 0 )
 do_heading( argc[1] );

Type & Run 1
nting Your Listings 27
 fprintf( stdprn, “%4d:\t%s”, line++, buffer );
 }

 fprintf( stdprn, “\f” );
 fclose(fp);
 return 0;
 }

 void do_heading( char *filename )
 {
 page++;

 if ( page > 1)
 fprintf( stdprn, “\f” );

 fprintf( stdprn, “Page: %d, %s\n\n”, page, filename );
 }
```

Using Win 8 + VS 2012. To compile this, opened Developer Command Prompt, and typed

```
cl print_it.c
```

Got this screen (bunch of errors and warnings)

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you carelessly copy-pasted. Start by replacing every `“` and `”` with `"`.

Then remove this:

```
Type & Run 1
nting Your Listings 27
```

Answer (score 1):

As @cnicutar [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12051899/151641), fix the broken double quotes first and remove the garbage.

However, you won't get this program compile with Visual C++ due to the fact there is no `stdprn` stream available on Windows

See [How can I make the printer work in C in MS VC++ Express edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2257218/151641) for details on how to work around it.